# AWS Amplify GraphQL Recusive Schema

Tags: reactjs, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I'm currently working on a React.js project and I am trying to create a nested Response component. I basically have data in the form of

```js
data = {
  id: 'some_id',
  response: 'lorem ipsum',
  parameters: {
    params: 'lorem ipsum',
  }
  child_responses: [
    id: 'some_id',
    response: 'lorem ipsum',
    parameters: {
      params: 'lorem ipsum',
    },
    child_responses: [],
  ]
}
```

I created created a GraphQL schema for the attributes but not sure how to deal with the child_responses field.

```
type Response @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner }]) {
  id: ID!
  response: String!
  parameters: AWSJSON,
  child_responses: *Not sure how to deal with this recursive relationship*
}
```

How can I set up the schema?

Comment: `child_responses: [Response]` is the generic GraphQL answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a one-to-many relationship like the following:

```
type Post @model {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  comments: [Comment] @hasMany
}

type Comment @model {
  id: ID!
  content: String!
}
```

Docs: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/data-modeling/#has-many-relationship

Note: Go to AWS Appsync and query the "Posts" to see the children "comments" in the response.